# Google Tag Assistant records multiple duplicate Google Analytics Tags

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

So since a few days my bounce rate dropped massively in Analytics. I found out the Google Tag Assistant records 3 Analytics Tags on the website, which apparently is a big reason why GA suddenly drops the bounce rate, but I can't figure out why. The URL is: https://www.krant.nl/abonnement/hp/index.html

[image: See Tag Assistant here]

Since I tried about everything, went back to the version where it still worked, still no luck. I also can't seem to find any weird things in the website code itself.

I hope the question is clear, if I need to provide any more information please let me know.

Comment: There are three tags because you have one page view and two events (you can see this when you click on the entries in Tag Assistant). Am I right to assume the noninteraction flag wasn't set for your events when you asked the question (in which case it would be nice if you could self-answer and accept) ?

Answer (score 1):

In your website it's firing Universal Analytics 3 times because you are using https://vwo.com/. If you will delete it, it will fix problem

Comment: Thanks Victor for your answer. Would it be enough to remove the GTM VWO events/tags firing or can it only be solved by removing the VWO code in the website itself?

Comment: Removing VWO code in the website should be enough, but i didn't test

Comment: I tested by removing the code from the site, unfortunately it didn't solve the problem so I added it back in for now. Any chance you have another solution?